# Svg image element not displaying in Safari

Tags: svg, safari

Safari browser (I'm testing under windows) seems having problem in displaying Svg Image element.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My first SVG</h1>

<img src="image.svg" />

</body>
</html>
```

And here is the content of the image.svg:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- Created with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/) -->
<svg
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
      <rect x="50" y="50" width="100" height="100" style="fill:blue"></rect>
      <rect id="foo" x="50" y="150" width="500" height="500" style="fill:green"></rect>
     <image x="50" y="10" width="200" height="200" xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="></image>
</svg>
```

Is there any solution or workaround to make this work in Safari?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I think there are two problems here:

1. You haven't said anything about how large your SVG image is. As a rule, you should at least include a `viewBox` attribute in the `<svg>` tag. For example:

   ```
   <svg width="250" height="250" viewBox="0 0 250 250" ... >
   ```
2. The other problem is that Safari isn't particularly brilliant at rendering SVGs. However, it tends to do better when you embed them with an `<iframe>` or `<object>` tag instead of using `<img>`. For example:

   ```
   <object data="image.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
   ```

   Also, make sure your server is delivering SVG content with the correct MIME type (`Content-Type: image/svg+xml`), as this can cause problems too.

---

So give this a try:

**HTML source:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1>My first SVG</h1>
<object data="image.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
</body>
</html>
```

**image.svg:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg width="250" height="250" viewBox="0 0 250 250"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
      <rect x="50" y="50" width="100" height="100" style="fill:blue"></rect>
      <rect id="foo" x="50" y="150" width="500" height="500" style="fill:green"></rect>
     <image x="50" y="10" width="200" height="200" xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="></image>
</svg>
```

Comment: Seems like object element is not clickable when you put it inside an <a> or <button>

Comment: Unfortunately its divided between browsers. In Safari it will render if the immediate parent has its height and width defined. In older IE/Edge the svg will fill the grand-parents view box requiring a child shim inside the defined container, which Safari then interprets as an ambiguous field. Having a grand-parent set with the size, and a parent-shim set as width=100%, and then the SVG usually works

Answer (score 40):

In the `<image>` tag inside the svg element, `href` works fine in Chrome. To work in older versions of Safari, you need `xlink:href`. (Also applies to the `<use>` tag.) Keep in mind `xlink:href` is deprecated and is being replaced by `href`. However, it was not supported until Safari 12.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/href

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" ...>
    <image href="data..." xlink:href="data...">
</svg>
```

Comment: Yaaaaas! Such an easy fix, and yet I spent 3 hours on it. :F

Comment: This does work, but what if I'm not able to use `xlink:href` on chrome? for some reason the whole thing gets removed.

Comment: OmarAguinaga, did you ever find the answer you were looking for?

Comment: This is still an issue as of May 30, 2018.  an image tag inside an svg requires xlink:href attribute in order for the latest version of Safari to render.  href on its own works for chrome, firefox, edge, but not safari.

For now, I have both href and xlink:href simultaneously, and they both work in all browsers.

Comment: I'm now using both href and xlink:href until I find a reason not to. Who knows when xlink:href support will actually be dropped? In any case, OP is already using xlink:href.

Comment: Oh, yeah! This fixed the problem in Safari for iPad (Safari desktop works as expected).

Answer (score 14):

Be sure to supply your `<svg>` tag with a height, width, and view box like so. Safari doesn't like it when height or width is set to `auto` for some reason. ⤵︎

```html
<svg height="16px" width="16px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100"><path d="M60......"></path></svg>
```

Comment: This one solved it for me.

Answer (score 4):

I just discovered this same problem when I checked an app I was working on in Safari, after having been using Chrome most of the time. I wrote this bit of TypeScript/jQuery code (easily enough turned into plain JavaScript) to solve the problem:

```
export function setSvgHref(elem: JQuery, href: string) {
  elem.attr('href', href);

  if (isSafari()) {
    elem.each(function() {
      this.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'href', href);
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case, the problem was related to `<mask>` tags in `svg`.
I deleted the following line in my `svg` component and it started to work on Safari.

```
<mask id="y9iogdw0wd" fill="#fff">
    <use xlink:href="#jz8vxv0q6c"/>
</mask>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with a wordmark (text that I use as a logo) that I saved as a .svg file. It was on my page with a `<img src="...svg">` but did not appear properly in Safari (current version as of July 2020). The SVG worked fine with FireFox, Chrome, and Brave.

I had created the SVG in Inkscape. I selected the entire object, then used Path -> Object to Path... and saved the resulting file.

This rendered properly in all four browsers. (I'm writing this here in case I have this problem again: it'll tell me what I did to fix it.)

Answer (score 0):

For modern Safari 15.6.1 (Desktop) it will render without any attributes, as long as the `height` and `width` are **BOTH** defined to something other than `auto` (default).

```html
<svg height="48" width="48">...</svg>
```

**HOWEVER**, to ensure it scales properly and can be resized with CSS, it's better to use the [viewBox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox) ratio and let CSS do what it does best (and yes, because of Safari, you still need to define both width and height):

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 48 48">...</svg>
```

```css
svg {
  width: 96px;
  height: 96px;
}
```