# SVG paths not displaying in Safari

Tags: javascript, html, svg, safari

I have an SVG file of icons that looks like this:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <path id="instagram" d="..."/>
  <path id="linkedin" d="..."/>
  <path id="twitter" d="..."/>
</svg>
```

And it's referenced in my HTML like this:

```
  <a href="...">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 32 32"><use xlink:href="icons.svg#instagram"></svg>
  </a>
  <a href="...">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 32 32"><use xlink:href="icons.svg#linkedin"></svg>
  </a>
  <a href="...">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 32 32"><use xlink:href="icons.svg#twitter"></svg>
  </a>
```

And, like [many questions before this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27245673/svg-image-element-not-displaying-in-safari), the SVGs aren't rendering in Safari on desktop nor mobile.

Is there a way to have them render with the `<svg>` tags that works in all browsers?  I'd like to not have to edit the CSS that styles the `<svg>` tags if possible.  Is the `<object>` tag the only solution that works across all browsers?  Is referring to the `id` of the path also valid with the `<object>` tag?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think safari supports external content for the `<use>` element.