# Why are these icons showing on Chrome but not on Safari?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made this [website](https://oasaleh.github.io/restaurant/) as part of the Odin Project curriculum and for some reason the social media icons (Facebook, Twitter, and Instagram) are showing on Chrome but not on Safari.

I tried to clear the cache and history on Safari.

Can anyone point out the compatibility issue and how to fix it?

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Svg image element not displaying in Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27245673/svg-image-element-not-displaying-in-safari)

Comment: Unfortunately @Jimenemex that does not solve my problem. I used the <object> but to no vail.

Comment: Have you added height and width of object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd like to thank every one who chimed in and helped! However, the issue was my AdBlocker! It was removing social media icons!

Answer (score 1):

I took the HTML from the website and made it into a snippet to test (with full URLs) Please try it and let me know what you see- it shows the icons on my Safari (on iPad IOS), though they are slightly overlapping each other.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Resturant</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://oasaleh.github.io/restaurant/index.css">
  <link rel="icon" href="https://oasaleh.github.io/restaurant/resources/tabIcon.png">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="content">
    <section id="header" class="undefined">
      <header id="title-bar" class="undefined">
        <p id="undefined" class="title">Halal Guys</p>
      </header>
    </section>
    <div id="nav-bar" class="undefined"><button id="Menu" class="nav bar item" href="">Menu</button><button id="Catering" class="nav bar item" href="">Catering</button><button id="ContactUs" class="nav bar item" href="">Contact Us</button></div>
    <div id="contentWindow" class="undefined">
      <ul id="menu" class="undefined">
        <li class="menu item">
          <p class="menu item name">Beef Gyro Platter</p> <img class="menu item photo" src="https://oasaleh.github.io/restaurant/resources/photos/food/beef-gyro-platter-530x530.jpeg"> </li>
        <li class="menu item">
          <p class="menu item name">Chicken Gyro Platter</p> <img class="menu item photo" src="https://oasaleh.github.io/restaurant/resources/photos/food/chicken-platter-530x530.jpeg"> </li>
        <li class="menu item">
          <p class="menu item name">Combo Platter</p> <img class="menu item photo" src="https://oasaleh.github.io/restaurant/resources/photos/food/combo-platter-530x530.jpeg"> </li>
        <li class="menu item">
          <p class="menu item name">Falafel Platter</p> <img class="menu item photo" src="https://oasaleh.github.io/restaurant/resources/photos/food/falafel-platter-530x530.jpeg"> </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <footer id="footerSection" class="undefined">
      <section id="socialMediaContact" class="undefined">
        <ul class="socialmedia list">
          <li class="socialmedia item"> <img class="social icon" id="iconFacebook" src="https://oasaleh.github.io/restaurant/resources/photos/icons/facebook-icon.svg"> </li>
          <li class="socialmedia item"> <img class="social icon" id="iconTwitter" src="https://oasaleh.github.io/restaurant/resources/photos/icons/twitter-icon.svg"> </li>
          <li class="socialmedia item"> <img class="social icon" id="iconInstagram" src="https://oasaleh.github.io/restaurant/resources/photos/icons/instagram-icon.svg"> </li>
        </ul>
      </section>
      <section id="rights" class="undefined">
        <div>
          <p>All Rights Reserved 2021</p>
        </div>
      </section>
    </footer>
  </div>
  <!--    <script src="https://oasaleh.github.io/restaurant/main.js"></script> -->


</body>

</html>
```

However, the actual website shows nothing and on inspection I see there is a main.js script. What does this do? It looks at first glance as though it has the HTML for the page in it. I suspect, but do not know, that this is overwriting the actual HTML in the page in some way.

Suggestion: try the page without this main.js and see what happens. Then investigate what this main.js is doing and why you have put it there

Comment: Your post made me realize that the problem with this was my AdBlocker! Just to answer your question, the main.js is the javascript that render the html. I am using webpack to build and bundle.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace img tag with object tag like this.

```
<img src="instagram-icon.svg">
```

with

```
<object data="instagram-icon.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
```

Try this code and if it doesn't work, let me know.

Comment: It is not working. I replaced <img> with <object>. Here is the line of code:
<li class="socialmedia item"> <object class="social icon" id="iconFacebook" data="resources/photos/icons/facebook-icon.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object> </li>

Comment: Have you added height and width of object?